# Mutually contradicting rules in Prolog

Tags: logic, programming-languages, prolog

What will happen in a Prolog program, if I set two rules/facts which contradict each other..
will it go with the rule/fact that appears first.. or it will show an error?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: First, think how do you write contradicting rules/facts. Give an example. There is negation in Prolog, but it is a foreign concept there. Likewise for the logical connective “absurd”.